# How to change/Overriding Gii result when use Yii Framework without have to change Yii Core

Tags: php, html, yii

How do I make a replacement result html tag when using Gii without having to change the yii core direct itself to change the outcome ???

Gii By default : `framework\gii\generators\crud\templates\default`

and result :

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
</div>
```

But if I want to get HTML Tag like :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $form->textField($model,'title'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or in any other form appropriate style css and html that I have.

What should I do to get the results of `Gii code generated` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The The Definitive Guide to Yii has an manual on extending Gii. You can find it here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#extending-gii